# Snowflake Unsupported Grant Type

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm running into an issue trying to execute a Token Request for OAuth in Snowflake.

I'm using Postman with a query param of `grant_type=authorization_code` but the oauth token-request endpoint continually sends back the following response.

```
{
    "data": null,
    "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
    "code": null,
    "message": "The provided grant type is not supported.",
    "success": false,
    "headers": null
}
```

Any ideas? Per the documentation this is one of the two supported grant types.

```
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/oauth-custom.html
```

API URL :

`https://example.com/oauth/token-request?grant_type=authorization_code&code=123&redirect_uri=https://localhost.com`

Comment: Can you please reinsert the link the the docs you found? You had your account URL there.

Comment: Thanks @GregPavlik. I put that link in there on purpose to show the format of the link and how I am specifying grant_type.

Comment: Makes sense. I you need it back to show the API call, you may want to obfuscate the actual account part of the URL. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you sir, I've updated it.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the Snowflake documentation is incorrect. I will be submitting a ticket to them to get it fixed.

The [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/oauth-custom.html#step-1-create-an-oauth-integration) indicates that you're supposed to include the items as query parameters; they belong in the POST body as per the standard, however.

Answer (score 1):

The values for token generation should be passed under x-www-form-urlencoded section and there the following values should be passed:

```
redirect_uri
grant_type
code
```

Under the Header section, following should be passed:

```
Authorization
```

The value for this would be:

```
Basic <base 64 encoded value for clientid:client secret>
```

The encoded value can be generated from: https://www.base64encode.org or you may generate it using code.

[image: Body of Request]

[image: Header Section]

Comment: Yes, correct. The documentation indicated that the redirect_uri, grant_type, and code should be passed as Query Parameters but the documentation is incorrect.